# How exactly does a pointer iterate through a string/array?

Tags: c++, string, pointers

So, I've recently learned that 'char*' is a synonym for 'string' and that is points to the first character of the string and also that you only need to know the address of the first character,and where the string ends to display
its contents. But I'm confused as to how the pointer iterates through the string.

Basically, why and how does this code:

```c
char *s="Hello";
cout<<s<<endl;
```

Output:`"Hello"` and not: `"H"`

Comment: It uses a loop to print characters until it finds a `'\0'` character.

Comment: Please add a tag for the language you are using (which is probably C?).

Comment: `char*` is **NOT** a synonym for `string` in C++. Neither is it in C, where `char*` is an array of char. It just happens to be used for storing a string of characters by terminating it with a NULL character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`operator<<` is overloaded for `char*` so it can iterate a null terminated string. It simply starts at the given character and then outputs in a loop until the null terminator is reached. For example, it does the equivalent of this:

```
ostream& operaror<<(ostream &os, const char *str)
{
    while (*str != '\0') {
        os << *str;
        ++str; // <-- moves to next character
    }
    return os;
}
```